# Where is the Artifactory OSS source code located?

Tags: open-source, artifactory

I can download the latest Artifactory OSS release (5.2.1), but I can't seem to find its source code.

The Artifactory documentation links to https://api.bintray.com/content/jfrog/artifactory/jfrog-artifactory-oss-$latest-sources.tar.gz;bt_package=jfrog-artifactory-oss-zip, but there's no source at that address.

Does anyone know what the real URL is, or if there's a public svn or git repo that I can clone?

Comment: https://bintray.com/jfrog/artifactory/jfrog-artifactory-oss-zip/4.15.0 - the downloads there look a lot like source code to me...

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth - Indeed, that does appear to be the source for 4.15.0 (a six-month-old release).  But that looks like the last one published.  If I want to see the source to the latest OSS binary release (5.2.1), or the tip of dev to consider contributing, I don't see anything more recent, which makes me wonder if the repo moved, or if the source-publishing stopped (either accidentally or intentionally).

Answer (score 7):

Thanks for letting us know.
We have uploaded the sources of version 5.2.1 to Bintray.
feel free to download the file:
https://api.bintray.com/content/jfrog/artifactory/jfrog-artifactory-oss-$latest-sources.tar.gz;bt_package=jfrog-artifactory-oss-zip

Comment: The link is broken! `message "Could not find artifact with path 'jfrog-artifactory-oss-5.4.6-sources.tar.gz'"` I'm trying to see if a problem I have is a bug on your side or mine, but I don't have any sources to look at!

Comment: https://api.bintray.com/content/jfrog/artifactory/jfrog-artifactory-oss-5.2.1-sources.tar.gz;bt_package=jfrog-artifactory-oss-zip works fine but is not the latest version

Comment: @DanielGray issue was resolved. The link is working now.

Comment: @Ariel Link is broken again. Gives the following error: `{"message":"Could not find artifact with path 'jfrog-artifactory-oss-6.2.0-sources.tar.gz'"}`

Comment: Will look into that on Sunday. Will make sure to update after.

Comment: @Ariel This missing source code seems to be a chronic problem. I inevitably need to consult it every time I run into an upgrade problem. Maybe JFrog could use something other than bintray for managing the source code artifacts.

Comment: @vallismortis The issue last time was not related to Bintray but to a file that was not published during the release cycle. I don't know if the issue this time has anything to do with Bintray so lets not jump into conclusions...

Comment: The file has been uploaded and released. Enjoy Artifactory 6.2.0 :)

Comment: @Ariel Wouldn't it be simpler to have a Github repo where you do a code dump from time to time? It would be trivial to automate for release and would make you much nicer OSS citizens, IMO.

Comment: @Ariel I think something went wrong publishing 6.11 since none of the 6.11 artifacts required to build 6.11 where published to BinTray. See for example 'artifactory-config' at https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter/org.artifactory%3Aartifactory-config

Comment: Thanks, @JasperSiepkes, I will check it with the relevant team and will update once available.

Comment: @JasperSiepkes Fixed. 6.11.1 was published to the location you mentioned 
https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter/org.artifactory%3Aartifactory-config

Comment: @JasperSiepkes Please note that the link you have used is not part of our release cycle. Therefore will not be deployed there all the time.
For the latest sources please use: https://api.bintray.com/content/jfrog/artifactory/jfrog-artifactory-oss-$latest-sources.tar.gz?bt_package=jfrog-artifactory-oss-zip

Comment: @Ariel Are the sources for the 7.X releases no longer public (7.4 is the latest release)? The source code releases seem to stop after 6.19.1. See https://api.bintray.com/content/jfrog/artifactory/jfrog-artifactory-oss-$latest-sources.tar.gz?bt_package=jfrog-artifactory-oss-zip and also on https://bintray.com/jfrog/artifactory/jfrog-artifactory-oss-zip 6.19.1 is also the latest.

Comment: @JasperSiepkes I've taken this for internal discussions. The Papi file was uploaded to Bintray. Will update about the sources once I'll have an answer.

Comment: @Ariel I was just wondering how things are progressing on your end. If you folks are going a different direction by not releasing the source of the 7.X branch that is of-course totally fine. You don't owe me anything in that sense and I'm grateful for the sources that were released.

Comment: @Ariel keep us informed when you have any news about the source code!

Comment: Hi all, please find below the link to download the 7.x sources file:
 https://releases.jfrog.io/artifactory/bintray-artifactory/org/artifactory/oss/jfrog-artifactory-oss/[RELEASE]/jfrog-artifactory-oss-[RELEASE]-sources.tar.gz.

Comment: @Ariel I tried to build the source, but something seems to be missing! I opened a question with all the errors I get, please check it out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64534185/cant-compile-artifactory-7-10-2

Comment: @Ariel (not sure if you are responsible for this). It looks like the source publishing has broken at [7.41.13](https://releases.jfrog.io/artifactory/bintray-artifactory/org/artifactory/oss/jfrog-artifactory-oss/7.41.13/). The [7.41.12](https://releases.jfrog.io/artifactory/bintray-artifactory/org/artifactory/oss/jfrog-artifactory-oss/7.41.12/) has a `sources` tarball. It is sporadic after that. Seems 7.49 and 7.55 do have more consistently.

Comment: 7.63.9 seems to be absent as well...

Answer (score 4):

For the 7.x releases you can find them here:

https://releases.jfrog.io/artifactory/bintray-artifactory/org/artifactory/oss/jfrog-artifactory-oss/7.10.2/

Comment: Those aren't the sources. Those are tarballs containing binaries of the "opensource" version but the actual sources are no where to be found there. Or atleast I don't see them with the latest version: https://releases.jfrog.io/artifactory/bintray-artifactory/org/artifactory/oss/jfrog-artifactory-oss/7.29.7/