# Can't compile Artifactory 7.10.2

Tags: java, maven, build, artifactory, packaging

After JFrog released the [source code for Artifactory 7.10.2](https://releases.jfrog.io/artifactory/bintray-artifactory/org/artifactory/oss/jfrog-artifactory-oss/7.10.2/), I tried to build it, without success.

The project seems to be a maven one (there is a `pom.xml` in the root project, so I guess so).
From the root of the project I gave the usual `mvn package`, but this resulted in an error:

```
$ mvn package
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for org.artifactory:artifactory-parent:7.10.2: Failure to find org.jfrog.common:jfrog-parent-pom:pom:7.10.2 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 21, column 13
 @ 
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project org.artifactory:artifactory-parent:7.10.2 (/tmp/jfrog-artifactory-7.10.2/pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM for org.artifactory:artifactory-parent:7.10.2: Failure to find org.jfrog.common:jfrog-parent-pom:pom:7.10.2 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 21, column 13 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/UnresolvableModelException
```

It seems that the project itself requires a local dependency, that it is not available to the `tar.gz` released though.
Looking at the 6.23.x source code there is a reference to `artifactory-parent` that is missing here, but I don't think it will compile using the old dependency.

Finally, I checked the `build/ci` folder, where there is a `pipelines_build.sh` script, but when launching it I have another error:

```
./pipelines_build.sh
./pipelines_build.sh: line 6: /tmp/build/ci/scripts/lib/buildInfoUtils.sh: No such file or directory
```

It seems that also here the tarball doesn't contain all the information in order to build the product.

For what it matters, I found the source code from this answer: [Where is the Artifactory OSS source code located?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43481238/9306378)

I'm doing something wrong? Can anyone help me building Artifactory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use JCenter not Maven central. Goto jcenter and download the settings.xml and then try again.